# MSB building error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Could you please let me know what can be the reason for the following error:

```
 Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
```

I am building my C project in the microsoft visual studio 2010.

thanks

[EDIT]

Following is the total error msg

```
  >Build started 7/5/2011 9:33:32 AM.
  1>InitializeBuildStatus:
  1>  Touching "Debug\final_version.unsuccessfulbuild".
  1>CustomBuild:
  1>  Performing Custom Build Tools
  1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5):  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
  1>
  1>Build FAILED.
  1>
  1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07
```

I am not using QT and others but I am using custome build to  make the `parser` compatible for the windows. Those parsers were coded for unix flatform.I am using bison and flex for 
getting the grammer useful for windows. After getting those grammar, I am trying to build the project with custome building the `lex` and `yacc` files.

Comment: Do you have a pre-build or post-build event set up? Are you using some toolkit like Qt? Can you post the complete output of MSBuild?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your quick reply. I have edited my post.

Comment: As I suspected, there's some kind of "CustomBuild" event going on, and that's what's throwing an error. What parser are you talking about? And if the tools are created for Unix, then they're probably not going to work properly on Windows. See what the custom build step is trying to execute (it's using the command prompt, `cmd.exe`, to do so) and find out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your custom build EXE is failing to start. In my case, the EXE was finding an old version of a DLL that was incompatible. I was getting the exact same error message, "code -1073741515" and all. I updated the DLL next to the EXE and the problem was solved.